# Problemas de logica para un sistema de inventario en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

he hecho mi par de aplicaciones en Rails, basicamente informativas, pero en esta ocasion se me ha pedido un sistema de inventario, estaba intentando plasmar la logica antes de realizarla, y realice un boceto en Excel, tomando esa idea, he querido pasarlo a Rails, solo que me encuentro con un pequeño problema, en Excel, creaba 3 hojas, para Inventario, Entradas y Salidas, en donde las entradas o sea las compras a los proveedores, alimentaba a Inventario, pero para evitar que se crearan datos duplicados, agregaba manualmente el producto a Inventario y desde compras, por medio de formulas, solo llamaba al codigo del producto, y me traia los datos que necesitaba, y solo agregaba la cantidad, precio y proveedor, sin embargo,  no estoy seguro si es la forma correcta de hacerlo, ya que mediante esa logica, tomo la idea que seran 3 modelos, uno de Inventario, Entradas y Salidas, la pregunta es ¿quien pertenece a quien? pensando mas detalladamente deduzco que inventario en si, son productos, por lo tanto, estos productos pertenecen a una Entrada, y las salidas, pertenecen siempre a Entradas? Agradeceria enormemente me ayudaran a aclarar esta duda de este trio de modelos, Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por supuesto podría haber muchas formas de hacerlo, pero tal vez esta te sirva para comenzar.

```
# esto es literalmente un producto con sus características
# no importa cuantos hay, aquí solo describes el producto
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :inventory 
  has_many :transactions
end

# Aquí puedes tener la cantidad de productos
# asi como las entradas y salidas
# incluso puedes tener varios inventarios (p.ej. por tienda)
class Inventory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products # podrás ver los productos en inventario
  has_many :transactions # las transacciones que han modificado el inventario
end

# Aquí puedes registrar las entradas y las salidas
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :inventory

  def output
    # transacciones de salida
  end

  def input
    # transacciones de entrada
  end
end
```

### Actualización en base comentarios:

```
class Producto < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :transaccions # así lo pluraliza rails
  has_many :ventas,  through: :transaccions
  has_many :compras, through: :transaccions
end

class Transaccion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :producto
  belongs_to :venta,  optional: true
  belongs_to :compra, optional: true
end

class Venta < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :transaccions # así lo pluraliza rails
  has_many :productos, through: :transaccions

end

class Compra < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :transaccions # así lo pluraliza rails
  has_many :productos, through: :transaccions
end

# regresa todas las ventas de ese producto
producto.ventas

# regresa todas las compras de ese producto  
producto.compras 

# regresa todos los productos en determinda venta
venta.productos

# regresa todos los productos en determinada compra
compra.productos
```

Más información sobre `has_many :through`: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Saludos Horacio, gracias por contestarme! Me parece mucho tu idea Horacio, aunque veo ciertos inconvenientes en el mismo, personalmente me gustaria tratar esos 3 modelos de forma independientes y no como metodos, en cuanto a productos e inventario, ¿no vendria siendo casi lo mismo? Si es el caso, el inventario unicamente me bastaria un controlador, solo para mostrar la vista, y que se alimente de Compras y Salidas, solo que al realizar la compra, si mantengo producto y compra como independientes, entonces tendria que anidar productos dentro del formulario de compras, no se si me logro explicar

Comment: La idea, es que al realizar una nueva entrada, se cree un nuevo producto o verifique si ya existe y que solo se actualize la cantidad, para que no se duplique

Comment: En particular par que 'cree un nuevo producto o verifique si ya existe' puedes utilizar `find_or_create_by` https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by

Comment: La razón por la que recomiendo tener un  modelo 'inventario' y otro 'producto', es por el principio de 'Responsabilidad Única'. Así el modelo 'producto' sólo sabe lo que hace que un 'producto' sea un 'producto', sin importar si hay uno o cien. Por otra parte el inventario no sabe si un producto es de un color u otro, pero si sabe cuantos hay. Pero claro, que puede funcionar de otras formas.

Comment: Anuque claro que puedes tener un modelo 'ventas' y otro 'compras', creo que sería mejor tener uno para las 'transacciones'. Siempre puedes tener un `scope` para que llames algo así como `Transaccion.ventas` y `Transaccion.compras`. Pero de esa forma no repites nada. De lo contrario los modelos ventas y compras se parecerían mucho. y tendrías que programar/mantener el doble de código. Pero claro, también podría funcionar con los modelos por separado.

Comment: En el caso de tener 2 o 3 modelos separados Horacio, dejame tomar bien la idea, tengo el modelo de Productos, que es el producto en si, el modelo de compras, y el modelo de ventas, todo bien ahi, por lo que veo inventario no necitara mas que un controlador el cual simplemente se mostrara en vista con datos alimentados desde productos, compras y salidas, por lo que mi duda aqui es ¿La compra pertenece al producto o el producto a la compra?

Comment: Qué tal utilizando `has_many :through`? Actualicé la respuesta utilizando por separado 'venta' y 'compra'.

Comment: Entonces un producto  'tiene muchas' ventas y también 'tiene muchas' compras. De la misma forma, una compra y/o venta puede 'tener muchos' productos.

Comment: Habia olvidado, agradecerte Horacio por tu tiempo, la forma primera que me explicastes sin el has_many :through fue mas que suficiente! y va fenomenal! Abrazos y Saludos! =D